# How to use data decoded from JSON in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

**Problem**

The data is successfully decoded from Reddit’s api and put into the variable `theUser` inside the `.onAppear {…}`, but when I try to use it I keep getting nil values.

**Code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var didAppear = false
    @State var theUser = getNilUser()
    var body: some View {
        Text("User Profile")
        Text(theUser.data.subreddit.display_name_prefixed ?? "No name found")
        .onAppear(perform: {
            theUser = getUser(withName: "markregg")
        })
        
    }
    func getUser(withName username: String) -> user {
        if !didAppear {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/user/\(username)/about.json") {
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                    do {
                        let decodedUser = try JSONDecoder().decode(user.self, from: data)
                        return decodedUser
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            didAppear = true
        } 
        return getNilUser()
    }
}
```

Edit: I’m very new to this so if I made a stupid mistake I’m sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can't get JSON data like that. You have to execute a HTTP request using the [`URLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) class in order to get the data and parse it.

```
let username = "markregg"
let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/user/\(username)/about.json")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else if let data = data {
        do {
            let decodedUser = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } else {
        print("Request failed")
    }
}.resume()
```

Another thing to note is that `URLSession` methods are asynchronous. In simple terms it means they take some time to execute and return the result. So you can't use a simple return statement like `return decodedUser` to get the result right away. Look into how to use `URLSession` more.

Comment: I edited the code to include a slightly tweaked version of your method where the result is assigned to `theUser` and the same issue happens. Inside the `.onAppear` The data is present and I can print out any value I want, outside of that in the rest of the view body `theUser`’s values are all nil.

Comment: @MarkReggiardo Look into how network calls are handled in SwiftUI. Here's a good [starting point](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui).