# Why is my data not returning to my UI but it’s being decoded fine in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, jsondecoder

I’ve posted about this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66865678/how-to-use-data-decoded-from-json-in-swiftui) and I made some changes to my code based on [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui) article but now my data is not even available in the `.onAppear {…}` like it was before. Basically, I can’t get the data from the reddit API and store it in the variable theUser.

Here’s my code and thank you for your time :)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var didAppear = false
    @State var theUser = getNilUser()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(theUser.data.subreddit.display_name_prefixed ?? "No name found")
            Text(theUser.data.subreddit.public_description ?? "No description found")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            getUser(withName: "markregg")
            print(theUser)
        })
    }
    func getUser(withName username: String) {
        if !didAppear {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/user/\(username)/about.json") else {
                print("Whoops")
                return
            }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        if let decodedUser = try? JSONDecoder().decode(user.self, from: data) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.theUser = decodedUser
                            }
                            return
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    print("Request failed")
                }
            }.resume()
            didAppear = true
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: When is called `print(theUser)` And when is called `self.theUser = decodedUser`? Add `print` if needed. And replace ``print(theUser)`with ``print("onAppear() theUser \(theUser)")` maybe, to not confuse with where you'll print it in ` self.theUser = decodedUser`. Also, dont use `try?`, you use a `do/catch`, don't you have an error?

Comment: The above comment is important. Also, in your last question that you linked to, the answerer explained that the network call is *asynchronous* and doesn't return right away. You're still trying to `print` right after starting the async call, when the data isn't actually there yet. Once you're sure your JSON is decoding correctly, try printing right after setting `self.theUser`. I'd also recommend moving all of the network code into a separate ObservableObject.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some quick changes to your code (it's quite late, sorry). Some comments: (1) should you use try? (with question mark) you don't need to catch error (will be never genereated), (2) why not using optional User type ?, (3) you dit set "Outgoing connections (client)" capability, didn't you?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var didAppear = false
    @State var theUser: User? // = getNilUser()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Display name: \(theUser?.data.subreddit.display_name_prefixed ?? "No name found")")
            Text("Public description: \(theUser?.data.subreddit.public_description ?? "No description found")")
        }
        .frame(width:200, height: 200)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            getUser(withName: "markregg")
        })
    }
    func getUser(withName username: String) {
        if !didAppear {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/user/\(username)/about.json") else {
                print("Whoops")
                return
            }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    if let decodedUser = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.theUser = decodedUser
                        }
                        return
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    print("Request failed")
                }
            }.resume()
            didAppear = true
        }
    }
}
```